# Did I just sort in O(n) on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js, complexity-theory

Using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) library, I tried to abuse the indexing of a JavaScript object, in order to sort an array `a` of integers or strings:

```
_(a).chain().indexBy(_.identity).values().value()
```

I realize it is kind of a "hack", but it actually yielded a sorted array in O(n) time...

Am I dreaming?

Comment: I don't know Javascript, but what the theory requires is that *comparison-based* sorting is Omega(n log n). If the keys have exploitable structure (e.g., they are strings or numbers), then faster sorting is often possible--linear in the case of fixed-length numbers.

Comment: What makes you think this runs in linear time and what makes you think this sorts the array?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to make your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is **not** a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort):

> A comparison sort is a type of sorting algorithm that only reads the
>   list elements through a single abstract comparison operation (often a
>   "less than or equal to" operator or a three-way comparison) that
>   determines which of two elements should occur first in the final
>   sorted list.

You are using knowledge about the structure of the values (i.e. knowing that they're integers or strings) in your algorithm, by using those integers/strings as indexes. You are not adhering to the limitations imposed on a comparison sort, and thus you are not restricted to the `O(n log n)` boundary on time complexity.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't actually sorting anything.

Instead, you're building a hashtable and traversing it in hash order, which may be the same as sorted order for some sets.

Comment: The implementation doesn't need to use hash tables to implement objects, but the order [is not guaranteed either way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to sort by O(n) using Bucket Sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort which is I believe what you attempted to write here, but as mentioned above you can't rely on the order of values of an object.

It is possible to sort this way in O(n) if you have limited number of values.

Comment: Well, everything running on a computer will have a limited number of values. I meant limited by a known constant, not by "n".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *are* dreaming :-)

It beggars belief that you would have found such a holy grail by accident. If that sequence of operations is a comparison-based sort, people who *know* this stuff have actually *proven* that it cannot be done in O(n) time.

I strongly suggest you run that code with dataset sizes of 10, 100, 1000, and so on and you'll *see* your assumption is incorrect.

Then check to see if you *are* actually sorting the array or whether this is just an artifact of its organisation. It seems very likely that the [`indexBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) is simply creating an index structure where the order just happens to be the sort order you want, not something that would be guaranteed for all inputs.

Comment: Doesn't look comparison-based to me, so your argument is invalid